# Как "перевернуть" вывод, т.е. строки сделать столбцами?

Tags: sql

Есть простенький запрос, неважно на каких данных

```
select item, count(*) from table group by item
```

Задание: "перевернуть" вывод, т.е. строки сделать столбцами.

Comment: А как вы себе это представляете? Ведь в одном столбце будут данные разных типов.

Comment: Вот именно . Нужен полный текст задания. Недавно похожее делал - группировал данные поставко по поставщикам в разрезе помесецам. Так что задание в студию с таблицей


Comment: У Oracle и T-SQL, например, есть для этого специальный оператор, Pivot называется. Прочитать можно тут: (http://info-comp.ru/obucheniest/435-pivot-unpivot-transact-sql.html)

Comment: @daydark a 5 лет назад это была веселая задачка

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При условии, что нам известны все возможные варианты `Items`, например 'Keyboard', 'Mouse'  и 'Printer':

```
select 
  sum(case Item when 'Keyboard' then 1 else 0 end) as Keyboard,
  sum(case Item when 'Mouse' then 1 else 0 end) as Mouse,
  sum(case Item when 'Printer' then 1 else 0 end) as Printer
from [table]
```

---

UPD1. Чуток почесав голову становится ясно, как повторить то же самое для произвольного неизвестного нам набора item-ов (но тип-то хотя бы знать надо).

```
declare @query varchar(MAX), @item varchar(50)
declare cur cursor for 
select distinct item from [table]

open cur

set @query = 'select '

fetch cur into @item
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
    set @query = @query + 'sum(case Item when ''' + @item + ''' then 1 else 0 end) as ' + @item + ','
    fetch cur into @item
end

set @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1) + ' from [table]'
execute(@query)

close cur
deallocate cur
```

---

UPD2. [[@minamoto](/users/3171/minamoto)](/users/3171/minamoto) дело говорит, жульничать плохо. Более достоверный вариант.

```
declare @query1 varchar(MAX), 
        @query2 varchar(MAX), 
        @item varchar(50),
        @i int

declare cur cursor for 
select distinct item from [table]

open cur

set @query1 = 'select '
set @query2 = 'select '
set @i = 0

fetch cur into @item
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
    set @query1 = @query1 + '''' + @item + ''' as col' + Cast(@i as varchar(50)) + ','
    set @query2 = @query2 + 'cast(sum(case Item when ''' + @item + ''' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar(50)),'
    set @i = @i + 1
    fetch cur into @item
end

set @query1 = LEFT(@query1, LEN(@query1) - 1) 
set @query2 = LEFT(@query2, LEN(@query2) - 1) + ' from [table]'
execute(@query1 + ' UNION ' + @query2 + ' order by col1 desc')

close cur
deallocate cur
```

ЗЫ. написано на T-SQL, если что. проверено на MSSQL 2005

Comment: да мне ет на надо =) просто разминка для других, вчера мне его задали - подумал, будет интересно для других =)

Comment: да я понял. вот и размялся )

Comment: Ошибка в том, что названия Item-ов выведены в виде заголовка таблицы, а не в виде первой строки. А задание было - перевернуть таблицу.

Comment: @minamoto, вы совершенно правы. просто в таком виде эти данные представляют собой хоть какую то структуру. но так и быть для вас UPD2.

Answer (score 0):

Я в таких ситуациях обычно использую PIVOT.
Как им пользоваться доходчиво написано [тут](http://alexanderkobelev.blogspot.ru/2013/04/tsql-pivot-and-unpuvot.html)
Названия столбцов "перевернутой" таблицы, правда я делал через динамический SQL(что не очень красиво), но работало.