# Mysql сортировка по дням для табеля

Tags: mysql

есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на названия полей не обращайте внимание

как это свести к виду

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

самое банальное - это сгруппировать по столбцу и джойнить столько раз, сколько столбцов, но думаю есть более удобное решение

Comment: Не надо приводить к такому виду на SQL. Ибо SQL не предназначен для вывода неопределенного в изначальном запросе количества колонок. Сделать обычную группировку по дням с подсчетом количеств с выдачей по вертикали, а в горизонталь разворачивать на клиенте

Comment: можно поподробнее? группировать на основании чего?

Comment: решение в лоб что то типа `select 'пришло' as type,пришел, count(1) from table group by пришел union select 'болеет',болезнь,count(1) from table group by болезнь union ...` при желании конечно за одно чтение таблицы можно сделать, но там с IF придется возится

Answer (score 1):

Это называется транспонирование таблицы. Почитайте http://easy4web.ru/?p=1099 - тут разжёвано как это сделать.

UPD:
Хотя не совсем транспонирование в прямом понимании термина, но суть одна.

Comment: а как реализовать группировку по дням?

Comment: Вот тут есть более универсаньные варианты http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82-%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8 - только запрос будет сложный, не берусь его вот так вот на ходу генерировать.

Comment: там жестяк полный. но даже если я переверну данные мне не отсортировать их по датам, которых нет

Comment: @des1roer ну тут либо жестяк либо не-гибкость, либо делаем это не на стороне sql - а на стороне клиента, который принимает данные от sql. Я бы конечно не занимался порнографией и выбрал вариант #3, а если нет доступа к коду клиента - сказать прогерам которые им занимаются, что по-хорошему можно только так)