# Как транспонировать таблицу в oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Буквально повернуть на 90 градусов, учитывая что кол-во строк (а  транспонировании - столбцов) все время разное и их названия меняются?

Comment: Вот здесь есть решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82-%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8
Но oracle ругается на "@"

Comment: В том решении не Oracle, а MSSQL 2005. Опишите задачу более полно. Желательно с примером, и что пытались сделать. Если оракл 11 версии и выше, возможно вам поможет `Pivot\Unpivot`

Comment: Если версия оракла выше 10, то можно использовать pivot http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html